# Alternative definition of Normalized Eisenstein Series

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

Prove that for $k \geq 4$, $E_k(z) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{2}  \displaystyle\sum_{m, n \in \mathbb{Z}\\ gcd(m,n) = 1} (mz + n)^{-k}$. 
The usual definition of $E_k(Z)$ is

$E_k(Z) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{2\zeta(k)}G_k(z)$ where

 $G_k(z) = \displaystyle\sum_{m, n}'(mz+n)^{-k}$, the primed summation means that the summation is taken over pairs of $m, n$ not both zero.

I have done this in the following way:

$G_k(z) = \displaystyle\sum_{m, n}'(mz+n)^{-k}$
 $ = \displaystyle \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} n^{-k} + z^{-k} \displaystyle \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} m^{-k} +\displaystyle \sum_{m, n \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}} (mz+n)^{-k}$

$=2\zeta(k) + 2z^{-k}\zeta(k) + \displaystyle \sum_{m, n \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}} (mz+n)^{-k}$

Thus $ E_k(z) = \displaystyle\frac{G_k(z)}{2\zeta(k)} = 1 + z^{-k} + \displaystyle\frac{1}{2\zeta(k)} \sum_{m, n \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}} (mz+n)^{-k}$. 
Now I do not understand how to proceed. 
 Helps are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See $40.1.19$ [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-030-56694-4_40.pdf).